# python code to get first two fields of each line of file

Tags: python

I currently have the following code which gets only the first column of each line of a file and puts it in a list:

```
GetTimes = [x.split(' ')[0]  for x in open(logfile).readlines()]
```

The problem is, I now want to grab the first two columns of each line of a file.  and below is the code I'm attempting to use:

```
GetTimes = [x.split(' ')[:2]  for x in open(logfile).readlines()]
list(GetTimes)[0][0] + " " + list(GetTimes)[0][1]
```

Where I get stuck is I don't know how to incorporate the above line that begins with "list" with the original `GetTimes` line of code.

**UPDATE:**

there is a log file that has the date stamp below:

```
2018-06-27 08:53:45 affa fafa faf afafaf
2018-06-27 08:53:45 affa fafa faf afafaf
```

I was getting only the value in the first column, which is 2018-06-27.  But, now, i want to get first and second column, and put them in a list.

below is my attempt:
               def thetimes():
                   mylist = []
                   for ealltime in GetTimes:
                       combing = ealltime[0:20]
                       lineTstamps = list(combing[0] + " " + combing[1])
                       mylist.append(lineTstamps)
                   return mylist
                print thetimes()

But when I run the above, i get this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./scans.py", line 353, in <module>
    print thetimes()
  File "./scans.py", line 350, in livestatuslogTimes
    lineTstamps = list(combing[0] + " " + combing[1])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by "incorporate"?

Comment: Are you trying to create a string with the first two elements from the list? i.e. `'{0[0]} {0[1]}'.format(GetTimes)`

Comment: Could you explain what you are expecting to do with *'above line that begins with "list"'*?

Comment: i have updated my original post. please review.

Answer (score 0):

Your `GetTimes = [x.split(' ')[:2]  for x in open(logfile).readlines()]` works just fine to get the first two columns(words). Since you used a list comprehension you've created a list of lists.
Your next line: `list(GetTimes)[0][0] + " " + list(GetTimes)[0][1]` is redundant as you don't need to convert `GetTimes` into a list when it is already a list and then you are adding column one of row one + column two of row one. This is already what is stored at `GetTimes[0]`.
Based off of the variable name im assuming the log file begins with a date/time stamps and that's what you're trying to grab? Effectively you can now index `GetTimes[0:len(GetTimes)]` to get the Date/time combo of a row and then further index `GetTimes[0:len(GetTimes)][0] or GetTimes[0:len(GetTimes)][1]` to get the specific date or time.

If you provide a bit more context as to what you're trying to do next after GetTimes we can help you incorporate it! Let us know!

Comment: @RoyMWell did you read my reply? I already figured that you were trying to grab a date/time stamp combo off the log. Your first line GetTimes = [x.split(' ')[:2]  for x in open(logfile).readlines()] already grabs the items and creates a list of list out of them succesfully. Again, your update is redundant in your just recreating whats already in GetTimes. Please review my reply to see how to properly index GetTimes so you can grab the dates and the times.